# What is the build command to deploy a repository from Netlify?

Tags: html, git, github, deployment, netlify

I have a GitHub repository that I want to deploy to Netlify. It is just HTML, CSS and JavaScript code. I connected my account to Netlify successfully, and made the deploy run correctly on the repository I wanted. However, when I tried to access the website through the link I set, there it was a 404 error. I went through the Netlify troubleshooting, but I tried their recommendations and none worked for me.

I am new to this and I may note some things:

1. I didn't specify a building command (I did a deploy before with another repository without it and it turned out fine)
2. When checking the deployment logs, I saw that 0 files were identified to upload (I am enclosing a screenshot).[image: here]
3. I do not have a wrapper folder for the files, they are direct children of the repository. My HTML file is named "index.html" too.

I think I may have to use a building command, but I don't know which I should use.